# How to print a parameter of a function outside of the function in LUA?

Tags: lua

So I can currently print `test` in `object1(test)` which gives the output of "Hello" using:

```
function object1(test)
    print(test)
end

--code--:Connect(object1)

--Output--
"Hello"
```

I want to use the `test` parameter in another function so I was trying to see if it would print outside of the function first:

```
function object1(test)
end
--code--:Connect(object1)

--Ways I've tried printing it--

print(test)
print(object1(test))
```

Eventually I want to just be able to call `test` from within a different function than `Object1` :

```
function object1(test)
end

function object2()
    print(test)
    print(object1(test))
end
--code--:Connect(object1)
--different code--:Connect(object2)

--Output--
"Hello"
```

Is this possible or is there any better alternative ways other than what I'm trying? Thanks

Comment: parameters are _passed_ to functions. you should already have the value of it stored outside of the function body anyways.

Comment: how can I store the value outside of the function? I've been trying to do that but not sure how.

Comment: Assign the value to a variable, then pass that variable to the function. Then, both you and the function have access to the same value.

Comment: So like this for example?
`test = ""` `function object(test)
end`
`

Comment: Please go through the tutorials first: http://lua-users.org/wiki/FunctionsTutorial

Comment: I've went through many tutorials and explanations of functions before asking this question but none relate to my specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the global value in different functions. It's good to keep the scope of a variable as short as possible.

```lua
function fn1(text)
  print(text, "from fn1")
  text = text .. "(changed by fn1)"
  return text
end

function fn2(text)
  print(text, "from fn2")
end

local testStr = "Hello Word"
testStr = fn1(testStr)
fn2(testStr)
```